# I can run my app at local. But when deploy to heroku, there is no page

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I can run my app at local normally by command 'node app.js'. But when i deploy my app to  heroku, there is no page was served. Only "Application error" and guide me to see deploy logs. But in the logs, the only thing i can see is the build successfully

This is my build log

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 14.x...
       Downloading and installing node 14.17.3...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.13
       
-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       
       > nodemon@2.0.9 postinstall /tmp/build_d8e7f0b8/node_modules/nodemon
       > node bin/postinstall || exit 0
       
       Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:
        > https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate
       
       
       > core-js@2.6.12 postinstall /tmp/build_d8e7f0b8/node_modules/core-js
       > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
       
       added 456 packages in 10.049s
       
-----> Build
       
-----> Caching build
       - node_modules
       
-----> Pruning devDependencies
       removed 38 packages and audited 418 packages in 3.719s
       
       20 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       found 7 vulnerabilities (3 low, 1 moderate, 3 high)
         run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
       
-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 42.8M
-----> Launching...
       Released v15
       https://test-server-2021.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "test-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Server test chung, với mục tiêu mọi thứ về server để ở đây.",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "server": "json-server db.json -p 5000 -w -d 0",
    "start": "node app.js"    
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/hainn2009/test-server.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/hainn2009/test-server/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/hainn2009/test-server#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "connect-mongodb-session": "^3.0.0",
    "csurf": "^1.11.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.2",
    "express-validator": "^6.12.1",
    "json-server": "^0.16.3",
    "mongodb": "^4.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.13.3",
    "nodemailer": "^6.6.3",
    "nodemailer-sendgrid-transport": "^0.2.0",
    "pg": "^8.6.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.6.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.9"
  },
  "nodemonConfig": {
    "ignore": [
      "test/*",
      "data/*",
      "*.json"
    ]
  }
}
```

I don't know what to do. May be some config option must be set ? What file does heroku find when start the app ? Does heroku find my 'app.js' file ? Only heroku'deploy tab, i only point to my github repository.

Thanks

Comment: include the heroku error log file data here. check if you've set the env variables properly

Comment: @Arka: i've included my build log. Please have a look.

Comment: Check the logs by heroku cli - `heroku logs`.

Answer (score 2):

I 've found the answer. When check heroku CLI logs.  I found out that i 've  hard coded my listen port 3000. When i change it to process.env.PORT for heroku automatic choose the port, my app is working right now.

I really appreciate for all your help. Thank you again.